# Cadena vacia al publicar proyecto de GraphQL y C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, asp.net-core, graphql

Buen dia tengo una aplicacion hecha en Visual Studio con C#, .Net Core y GraphQL

En la solucion todo anda bien, la ejecuto y puedo consultar los datos... Pero cuando la publico ejecuto una query y me retorna una cadena vacía

[image: Imagen cuando lo publico]

[image: Imagen cuando lo ejecuto en la solucion de desarrollo]

Deberia de mostrarme los datos asi a como estan en la imagen que es cuando ejecuto la aplicacion desde la solución

Comment: que es esa pantalla que se visualiza en la imagen? con que libreria implementas GraphQL en .net ? o a que servicio estas queriendo consultar

Comment: hola leandro agradezco mucho tu comentario, estoy usando la libreria de GraphQL 2.4.0 y GraphiQL 1.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolverlo siguiendo los enlaces que estan en la respuesta

[image: Agregando un segundo parametro UseGraphiQL exclusivamente cuando lo alojamos en un servidor IIS]

[image: Estructura del proyecto en el IIS]

[image: Imagen con los datos retornados del servicio]

https://github.com/JosephWoodward/graphiql-dotnet

https://github.com/JosephWoodward/graphiql-dotnet/issues/6